# Error while Building 'Release' in my project (having custom controls)

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, build-process

I was building an Image Viewer Application **with 2 custom controls in my project**.

1. A list box with the image thumbnails + image name
   from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/imagelistbox.aspx

and

1. A picture box control with Zoom and pan capability
   from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/PanZoomExample.aspx?msg=2139768

I added them both in my Toolbox by Right Click>Select Items>Browse...

When I change the **build configuration** to **Release** the application fails to build and **gives the following errors**:

1.'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
D:\My Corner\My Docs\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myCanvas\myCanvas

in

```
private Controls.Development.ImageListBox listBox1;
this.listBox1 = new Controls.Development.ImageListBox();
```

2.'The type or namespace name 'Controls' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\My Corner\My Docs\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myCanvas\myCanvas\Form1.Designer.c

in

```
using Controls.Development;
private Controls.Development.ImageListBox listBox1;
```

3.The type or namespace name 'ImageListBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\My Corner\My Docs\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myCanvas\myCanvas\Form1.cs

in

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new ImageListBoxItem(i.ImageName, imgList.Count - 1));
```

**Although when I change the Build configuration to "Debug" the application builds fine.**

Please help on this.
Thanks guys!

Comment: @user.... Check the platform on the release build settings... Sometimes the settings are changed to any cpu or x64 when the components you're using might not be.

Comment: Do a "batch build" with all projects and configurations.  "Build...Batch Build" menu

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because of conflict between the windows forms Controls "the public Controls collection property" and the Controls namespace "Controls.Development" try make an elias to that namespace like:

```
using ControlsDevelopment = Controls.Development;
```

or
in line

`global::Controls.Development;`

Comment: @user575556: did you try this, does it solves your code problems.